# why the same code got different results when using query_posts in functions.php and index.php

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, hooks

I am using WordPress 3.5, and my blog sites have many registered users. After they log in, I want them to see just their own posts, not others.

So I added this to my `functions.php`, but I get a blank page.

```
function only_login_user_post_on_homepage() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    query_posts('author=', $current_user -> ID);
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_login_user_post_on_homepage' );
```

So, I comment out the `add_action`, then go to `index.php`, add the same code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
query_posts("author=".$current_user -> ID);
```

Yeah, got the results, I don't know why? The code are the same, but why I got different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code example, you hook into the `pre_get_posts` action, which fires during the main query. But instead of manipulating *that* query, you trigger another one using `query_posts()`, which fires the hook again, and you end up with an infinite loop.

With the second code example, you're just overriding the main query after it's occurred. But whilst it works, you've ended up with a redundant, time-consuming query.

You're almost there, and props for your efforts, so let's bring it together:

```
function wpse_103997_only_posts_by_current_user( $wp_query ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_home() )
        $wp_query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_103997_only_posts_by_current_user' );
```

Comment: thanks man. And which one is better, if I use the first method, that it is to say, everytime and everywhere when I need to query a post, will be invoke this method. But when I use the second method, I just invoke once, just when user visit his/her home page. So the second one is better ?

Comment: You're right! I've edited my answer, so that it only operates on the *main* query. Avoid the second method as you end up with unnecessary resource-sapping queries.